# Static html taking 15+ seconds to load in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, jersey-2.0

I have a simple Java REST API app served by Jersey. But just the loading (no requests, I checked the Chrome Network view) of static HTML is taking 15+ seconds. Logs don't seem to indicate anything awry. What could cause this? I've tried several methods of rendering static pages (forwardOn404 and staticContentRegex), but only one worked. Tracing doesn't work either.

I'm on Jersey 2.7

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>
            io.swagger.jaxrs.listing, com.btjroq.user.UserApi,com.btjroq.user.CreateUserApi,com.btjroq.twitter.TwitterApi,com.btjroq.stats.StatsApi
        </param-value>
    </init-param>

    <!--<init-param>-->
        <!--<param-name>jersey.config.servlet.servlet.forwardOn404</param-name>-->
        <!--<param-value>true</param-value>-->
    <!--</init-param>-->

    <!--<init-param>-->
        <!--<param-name>jersey.config.servlet.servlet.staticContentRegex</param-name>-->
        <!--&lt;!&ndash;<param-value>/.*html</param-value>&ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--<param-value>/(pages/.*|minoral/.*|js/.*|css/.*|bower_components/.*|apidocs/.*|swagger/.*)</param-value>-->
    <!--</init-param>-->


    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.tracing.threshold</param-name>
        <param-value>VERBOSE</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.tracing.type</param-name>
    <param-value>ALL</param-value>
    </init-param>



    <!--<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>-->
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>



<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/bower_components/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>



<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/minoral/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/swagger/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>pages/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<filter>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RedirectCallback</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.auth0.Auth0ServletCallback</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>auth0.redirect_on_success</param-name>
        <param-value>/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>auth0.redirect_on_error</param-name>
        <param-value>/login</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RedirectCallback</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/callback</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>WarmupServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.btjroq.WarmupServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>


</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WarmupServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WarmupServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>JWTFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.btjroq.util.JWTFilter</filter-class>

</filter>

<!-- We are going to restrict /api/* paths -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>JWTFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*/private/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>



</web-app>
```

Comment: Is this the very first time you're accessing the HTML after the server starts? Or does it take the same amount of time every time you access it?

Comment: It takes the same amount every time I access it.